# In a Multiple regression analysis (2 DV and 5IV)- can i run the analysis with only one DV transformed and the others in their original form?

Tags: regression, manova

i would like to run the following regression: 2 DV out of which 1 is in its original form and one is transformed (due to non-normality) to a squared transformation. Can i still run this regression or would i have to transform the other DV in the same format (squared transformation)

Many thanks in advance!

regards,

Clara

Comment: Clara, could you please clarify what type of regression/model you use? You say that you have 2 dependent variables, so do you calculate 2 separate regressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the DV don't have to be normal, the residuals do.

Second, if the residuals indicate problems, there may be various solutions - possibly transforming a DV, but possibly other things. It depends on the nature of your regression, you'd have to provide a lot more details for a good answer. On my blog I wrote a post called [How to Ask a Statistics Question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) which may help you formulate a better question.

Third, if you determine that you *do* need to transform one DV, there is no statistical necessity to transform the other, but there may be substantive reasons for doing so.

Finally, typically "multiple regression" is used to mean one DV and more than one IV; with more than one DV the term is "multivariate regression".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. i am sorry i was not being more specific. i know that the residuals have to be normal and i would not like to discuss whether the variable is normal or not but simply whether i could use a transformed and an non-transformed (just original, sorry i have a lack of a better word) dependent variable in my multivariate regression (sorry for using the wrong term). i think if anyone knows this in general then this could be answered with a yes or no, i would be very grateful :)

Comment: See my third point. The answer is yes.